# Why is my Editor's Completed event firing every time i tap on it?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My **Xamarin.Forms** app has a **ListView** where every **ViewCell** contains an **Editor**. Whenever the **Editor** is tapped, the  `Focused` event fires, but so does the `Completed` event even though **Done** or **Enter** hasn't been pressed on the keyboard.

Does anyone know what's going on and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the TextChanged event instead
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor

```
void EditorTextChanged (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var oldText = e.OldTextValue;
   var newText = e.NewTextValue;
}
```

Comment: But what if he NEEDS to use Completed?

I think it is fair to advice on use another EventHandler, but you are not really attempting to answer the question as stated in OP...

Answer (score 1):

### The Source of your problem

The problem you are experiencing, it think, is that once you have tapped an **Editor**, when you tap another one, the first will react as `Completed`, and the new one tapped reacts as `Focused`. From there on, each time you tap on an editor both EventHandlers will be called: `Completed` to indicate that the previous **Editor** *Completed*! and `Focused` to indicate that the new editor *Focused*.

---

### Possible work around

**Disclaimer: The code shown below is only supposed to suggest a way on how to work around this issue, and by no means am i trying to say that it is optimal or production code.**

I assume you decided to use the approach you are using because you think it is the best for your use case.

Having said that, if i had to work around your issue i would extend the object you are using to feed the **ListView** to include an ***id***, and then retrieve that ***id*** in the `EventHandler` in order to know which item exactly is firing the **event**.

Look, for example, to explore your issue i defined the following object

```
public class People
{

    public int id { get; set; }

    public String FullName { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsVisible { get; set; }

}
```

then in the `OnAppearing` method i wrote

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    List<People> i = new List<People>() { new People() { id = 0 }, new People() { id = 1 } };

    BindingContext = i;

    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

In **XAML** i created a simple **ListView** as

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Editor Focused="Editor_Focused"
                            Completed="Editor_Completed"/>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And so, in the ***code behind*** i was able to react in the `EventHandler`s accordingly

```
private void Editor_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{

    var tappedItemId = ((People)((Editor)sender).BindingContext).id;

}

private void Editor_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var tappedItemId = ((People)((Editor)sender).BindingContext).id;

}
```

I hope you can see through your problem after reading this.

*Happy coding!*

Comment: @Nick, if this post answered your question, please consider marking it as Answer. In this way you increase the usefulness of your own Post, to other developers who look for an solution for that same or similar issue.